# Package ‘adegenet’ version 2.1.4 cannot be unloaded in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use a function in the R package adegenet
It seems like it will install fine, but then when i call the package i get an error.

```
> install.packages("adegenet")
Installing package into ‘/Users/j2/Library/R/4.1/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/bin/macosx/contrib/4.1/adegenet_2.1.5.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2830546 bytes (2.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.7 MB

The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/p9/cy6q_pk935z1dfplsjrts30h0000gr/T//RtmpZXEMHg/downloaded_packages
> library(adegenet)
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Package ‘adegenet’ version 2.1.4 cannot be unloaded:
 Error in unloadNamespace(package) : namespace ‘adegenet’ is imported by ‘adephylo’ so cannot be unloaded
```

I'm not sure if the problem is with the install or calling the library. Any advice would be appreceated.
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but did you already have `adegenet` loaded in your session when you then (re) installed it? It is generally best to do one's library updates in a clean session to avoid complications. So, it looks like you're doing something with adephylo, adegenet is called by adephylo, then the system tries to save you by detaching adegenet prior to your install.packages, but can't, and thankfully errors. Or such a story could be told.

Comment: Could be. I did try and remove it and reinstall it and got the same message. But when i quit R and reopened, i had not problems. I did however get a similar message when i tried to call the package PopGenReport